# Performing background BLE scans without being tied to Main Activity context

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to start a BLE scan from a `Worker` class in Android, but when I go to initialize the necessary variables for Bluetooth scanning (`BluetoothManager`, `BluetoothAdapter`, `BluetoothLeScanner`), I realize that these require a reference to the context in order to be initialized. I understand that the `Worker` class requires the context as a parameter when it gets created (I don't know which context), but in my case, the `Worker` needs to continue doing periodic BLE scans in the background, even when the app is out of focus or destroyed. How can I perform BLE scans from a `Worker` class without being tied to the `Main Activity` context so that the scans continue in spite of the Activity lifecycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the context in your worker class:

```kotlin
import android.content.Context
import androidx.work.Worker
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters

class BleScanWorker(
    private val context: Context, 
    workerParams: WorkerParameters
) : Worker(context, workerParams) {
    override fun doWork(): Result {
        val bleManager = context
            .getSystemService(BluetoothManager::class.java)
        val btAdapter = bleManager?.adapter
        // TODO: Perform the scan
        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

Comment: But where does the Worker get the context from? Since the context gets passed in through the constructor

Comment: It is automatically provided when you create the work request. For example: `val bleScanWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<BleScanWorker>().build()`